# TextView, ListView is null then returning in onActivityResult

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview, onactivityresult

In `MainActivity` i have a `TextView`. It gets instantiated in `onCreate()`.

I press a button and begin another activity calling `startActivityForResult()`.

Then I return to the `MainActivity` and `onActivityResult()` is called. In this method I want to update the TextView with new text, but it's null, resulting to `NullPointerException`.

I would like to note that this error does not always occur, but sometimes and somewhere about 2% of my users.

1. Why may it happen?
2. Should I use `onSaveInstanceState()`/`onRestoreInstanceState()`?

p.s. *I have read it is better updating a textview in `onResume()` or `onRestart()` method because `TextView` (and rest of Views) restores its value in `onResume()` method, but this method comes after `onActivityResult()`, so TextView may become null.*

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;
Button btn;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextVIew);
   tv.setText("Text1");

} // end onCreate


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
        tv.setText("Text2");
    }
}    


public void onClickBtn(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); 
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
} }
```

Comment: Can you please post your Activity over here for better understanding,Thanks